# Sketchware: Syntax error on token ".", super expected after this token

Tags: java, android

like previously I am making an app and there's one error (finally) in that.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View_v) {
            Email = edittext1.getText().toString();
            Password = edittext1.getText().toString();
            if (!((Email.trim().length() == 0) && (Password.trim().length() == 0 ))) {
                final ProgressDialog pg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
                pg.setCancelable(false); 
                pg.setMessage("loading...");
                pg.show();
```

Now it makes another error:

```
ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
pg.setCancelable(false); 
pg.setMessage("loading..."); pg.show();
                             ˆ
Syntax error on token ".", super expected after this token
```

Comment: Is this a copy paste error  @Override
        public void onClick(View_v)  It should be normally  public void onClick(View view)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View_v) {
```

Instead, it should be

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
```

Comment: Ok, but there's one problem. I am using Sketchware instead Android Studio. Do you know how to edit it?